# Neo4J - Return Node Name instead of ID

Tags: neo4j, nodes, relationships

I would like to know how I can return the node names instead of the node IDs in the Java console.

The following output is shown in the console:

[image]

The desired output should look like:

[image]

Just without all the information but only with the Node names (which equal Airportnames).

My Java code looks like the following:

```
    package com.routesNeo4j;

import org.neo4j.driver.v1.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by e on 11.06.17.
 */
public class Neo4JRouting implements AutoCloseable, Neo4J_Connector {

    static Driver driver;


    public Neo4JRouting(String startAirport, String destinationAirport, StatementResult shortestPath) {

        driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://ec2-13-58-101-13.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7687",
                AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "Einloggen_123"));

        try(Session session = driver.session()) {

            shortestPath = session.run("MATCH (a:" + startAirport.toLowerCase() + "), (b:" + destinationAirport.toLowerCase()
            + "), p = allShortestPaths((a)-[r*1..4]-(b)) UNWIND rels(p) AS rel RETURN nodes(p), sum(rel.weight) " +
                    "AS weight ORDER BY sum(rel.weight)");


            List<Record> storeList = storeList(shortestPath);
            while (shortestPath.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(shortestPath.next().toString());
            }
            System.out.println(storeList);


        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public List<Record> storeList(StatementResult statementResult) {

        List<Record> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (statementResult.hasNext()) {

            list.add(statementResult.next());

        }

        return list;

    }

    @Override
    public Driver runDriver(String user, AuthToken basicAuthToken) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {

    }

}
```

I am looking forward to your answers. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Every row you are returning contains a list of nodes and a weight. That's what you ask in your query and that's what you get. So you have to "unpack" that result into the format that you desire.

Couple of code-snippets to show what I mean :

```
        StatementResult vResult = vSession.run(aCypher);

        while (vResult.hasNext()) {
            Record vRecord = vResult.next();

            vMutator.pushNode("row");

            for (Pair <String, Value> vListEntry : vRecord.fields()) {
                process_listentry(vSession, vMutator, vListEntry.key(), vListEntry.value());
            }

            vMutator.popNode(); // row
        }
```

and then in process_listentry :

```
private void process_listentry(Session vSession, IHDSMutator vMutator, String vKey, Value vValue) {
...
    else if (vValue.type().equals(vSession.typeSystem().NODE())){
        vMutator.pushNode(vKey);
        vMutator.addNode("_id", Long.toString(vValue.asNode().id()));
        for (String lLabel : vValue.asNode().labels()) {
            vMutator.addNode("_label", lLabel);
        }
        for (String lKey : vValue.asNode().keys()) {
            Value lValue = vValue.asNode().get(lKey);
            process_listentry(vSession, vMutator, lKey, lValue);
        }
        vMutator.popNode();
    }
```

...
but it does depend on what you ask in the query and thus have to unpack ...

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: IHDSMutator <-- What is this? Looking it up, I don't find any package or lib for that. Can you please explain?

Comment: It's just an example structure that I use to return my results in. It's actually a Hierarchical Data Structure (HDS), similar to an XML document. That's not the point of my example, the point is that you've got to process the result you get from the query in order to extract the actual data from it. In fact you don't even need a structure to keep the results in if you only want to print them to the console.